AVAssetWriterInputTaggedPixelBufferGroupAdaptor.appendTaggedBuffers return false on iOS, but macOS OK
I currently write an iOS app in Swift to do "Side-By-Side Video to MV-HEVC format" following the Apple Official document: Converting side-by-side 3D video to multiview HEVC.
The sample code by Apple is written for macOS command line, and I want to move it into an iOS app. When using totally the same conversion code in iOS, the line usually returns false during conversion:
if !bufferInputAdapter.appendTaggedBuffers(taggedBuffers, withPresentationTime: newPTS) {
    fatalError("Failed to append tagged buffers to multiview output")
}

I print out the newPTS for debugging, it returns false at different time and sometimes pass all the conversion. So I don't know where is the different from macOS and iOS.
Have I missed anything important that I should be aware of when it comes to iOS?

updated 20240508
I found iPad Air M1 can run well and no issue, macbook Air M1 too.
Is the sample code something only for M1 or laptop/iPadOS only?

I found the same app on iPhone 15 Pro MAX is running well. Originally running on iPhone 14 Pro, and the source video is in 7680x2160. I think that might be the memory not enough issue? But I didn't see the memory load very high in XCode debug navigator

I hope you can see the updated answer. iPhone 14 Pro Max now exports the MV-HEVC correctly. –

When fatalError("Failed to append tagged buffers to multiview output") occurs, you can print out the underlying error with this function:
private func checkAssetWriterStatus(assetWriter: AVAssetWriter) {
    if assetWriter.status == .failed, let error = assetWriter.error {
        let nsError = error as NSError
        print("Asset writer failed with error: \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
    } else if assetWriter.status == .cancelled {
        print("Asset writer was cancelled")
    } else if assetWriter.status == .completed {
        print("Asset writer completed successfully")
    }
}

if you do that, you will find the error is AVLocalizedErrorWithUnderlyingOSStatus: Returning error (AVFoundationErrorDomain / -11819) status (-16155)
And -11819 is an iOS specific error defined in AVError.h
    AVErrorDeviceLockedForConfigurationByAnotherProcess = -11817,
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
    AVErrorSessionWasInterrupted                        = -11818,
    AVErrorMediaServicesWereReset                       = -11819,
#endif

AVErrorMediaServicesWereReset means apple's backend VideoToolbox session is crashed.

Update: Figured out why the function crashed on iPhone 14 Pro Max, it was a memory leak bug that we wrote.
Pay attention to the documentation of method requestMediaDataWhenReady:

The callback you provide appends media data to the input until its isReadyForMoreMediaData property becomes false,

meaning the closure will be invoked repeatedly, so both the session & pixelBufferPool should not be created repeatedly in the closure of the isReadyForMoreMediaData method. This is unnecessary and wasteful, as these resources can be reused across multiple frames.
The VTPixelTransferSession and CVPixelBufferPool are not lightweight objects. They consume a significant amount of memory and other system resources. Creating a new one for each frame can quickly exhaust the available resources, leading to a memory leak.
Even though Swift's ARC will automatically deallocate these objects when they are no longer needed, the problem is that you're creating new ones faster than they can be deallocated.
So the correct code excerpt should look like:
        var session: VTPixelTransferSession? = nil
        guard VTPixelTransferSessionCreate(allocator: kCFAllocatorDefault, pixelTransferSessionOut: &session) == noErr, let session else {
          fatalError("Failed to create pixel transfer")
        }
        
        var pixelBufferPool: CVPixelBufferPool? = nil
        
        if pixelBufferPool == nil {
          let bufferPoolSettings: [String: Any] = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: NSNumber(value: kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB),
                                                   kCVPixelBufferWidthKey as String: self.eyeFrameSize.width,
                                                   kCVPixelBufferHeightKey as String: self.eyeFrameSize.height,
                                                   kCVPixelBufferIOSurfacePropertiesKey as String: [String: String]()
          ]
          CVPixelBufferPoolCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, nil, bufferPoolSettings as NSDictionary, &pixelBufferPool)
        }
        
        guard let pixelBufferPool else {
          fatalError("Failed to create pixel buffer pool")
        }
        
        // The dispatch queue executes the closure when media reads from the input file are available.
        frameInput.requestMediaDataWhenReady(on: DispatchQueue(label: "Multiview HEVC Writer")) {
          
          /* Session/pixelBufferPool shouldn't be recreated, this closure is called repeatly.
          var session: VTPixelTransferSession? = nil
          guard VTPixelTransferSessionCreate(allocator: kCFAllocatorDefault, pixelTransferSessionOut: &session) == noErr, let session else {
            fatalError("Failed to create pixel transfer")
          }
           
          var pixelBufferPool: CVPixelBufferPool? = nil
           
          if pixelBufferPool == nil {
          let bufferPoolSettings: [String: Any] = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: NSNumber(value: kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB),
           kCVPixelBufferWidthKey as String: self.eyeFrameSize.width,
           kCVPixelBufferHeightKey as String: self.eyeFrameSize.height,
           kCVPixelBufferIOSurfacePropertiesKey as String: [String: String]()
          ]
          CVPixelBufferPoolCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, nil, bufferPoolSettings as NSDictionary, &pixelBufferPool)
          }
          */
          
          
          // Handling all available frames within the closure improves performance.
          while frameInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData && bufferInputAdapter.assetWriterInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData {
            if let sampleBuffer = self.sideBySideTrack.copyNextSampleBuffer() {
              
              guard let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else {
                fatalError("Failed to load source samples as an image buffer")
              }
              
              let taggedBuffers = self.convertFrame(fromSideBySide: imageBuffer, with: pixelBufferPool, in: session)
              let newPTS = sampleBuffer.outputPresentationTimeStamp
              
              if !bufferInputAdapter.appendTaggedBuffers(taggedBuffers, withPresentationTime: newPTS) {
                fatalError("Failed to append tagged buffers to multiview output")
              }
            } else {
              frameInput.markAsFinished()
              multiviewWriter.finishWriting {
                continuation.resume()
              }
              
              break
            }
          }
        }

I have created a working example to my GitHub repo HERE
Now I can export the MV-HEVC video file correctly everytime.

Cheers.

I tried on my iPhone 14 Pro and it works! But no luck on iPhone SE 3. It runs farther with sleep than change the requestMediaDataWhenReady position. Maybe the memory is the main issue.

Poor memory size for se3

It seems to be RAM issue that iPhone 14 Pro only gets 6GB but iPhone 15 Pro MAX has 8GB. So it can append tagged buffer on iPhone 15 Pro MAX.

Updated 2024/05/08
I think this is not the reason since Spatialify can do on iPhone 14 Pro. Thus, I canceled the resolve check.
